# Kubernetes kube-dns restarts on master node

Tags: kubernetes, ubuntu-16.04, kube-dns

I have Kubernetes cluster on Ubuntu 16.04 servers, deployed using Kubespray.

Kube-dns pod is restarting continuously on master node. It has restarted 3454 times.

Can anyone let me know how to troubleshoot and solve this issue?

Starting logs of kube-dns:
[# 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh5Kc.png), [# 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8Xuj.png)

k8s-cluster.yml
[#1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcuDa.png) [#2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jAlK.png)

Comment: Please clarify your question and requirement in details. How can some one help you by providing only link or image. Put your code in text format.

Comment: @Suraj Kumar Please check.

Comment: Can you show your `yaml` files?

Comment: please check k8s-cluster.yml

Answer (score 0):

`SkyDNS` by default forwards the nameservers to the ones listed in the `/etc/resolv.conf`. Since `SkyDNS` runs inside the `kube-dns` pod as a cluster addon, it inherits the configuration of `/etc/resolv.conf` from its host as described in the `kube-dns` [documentations](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/dns/kube-dns).

From your error, it looks like your host's `/etc/resolv.conf` is configured to use `10.233.100.1` as its nameserver and that becomes the forwarding server in your `SkyDNS` config. Looks like `10.233.100.1` is not routable from your Kubernetes cluster and this is the reason why you are getting the error:

```
skydns: failure to forward request "read udp 10.233.100.1:40155->ourdnsserverIP:53:  i/o timeout"
```

The solution would be to change the flag `--nameservers` in the `SkyDNS` configuration. I said change because currently you have it set to "" and you might change it to `nameservers=8.8.8.8:53,8.8.4.4:53`.